# Pandoc: Separate table of contents for each section

Tags: pandoc

I am converting Markdown to HTML with Pandoc. With `--toc`, Pandoc generates a table of contents and inserts it under the first H1 heading (of which there is only one).

I would like it to have a separate, additional table of contents for each subheading. More specifically, I would like a small local table of contents under each H3.

Can Pandoc do that, and if yes, how?

Comment: you could run pandoc once for each section... e.g. by using a bash script... but maybe you're better off post-processing the HTML with js or whatever...

Comment: @mb21 I received a solution elsewhere, see posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer on [the pandoc-discuss mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/YA20DfSuQdY) in the form of a Lua filter.

Quoting from the author of the solution:

> - Warning: Assumes that all chapters are heading level 2 — change the `chapter_level` and `toc_level` variables to match!
> - Warning: Assumes that each section/chapter has a unique identifier!

```lua
local chapter_level = 2
local toc_level = 3
local headings = {}
local current_chapter = nil

local function collect_headings (head)
  if head.level == chapter_level then
    local id = head.identifier
    current_chapter = {
      chapter = id,
      toc = {},
    }
    headings[id] = current_chapter
  elseif head.level == toc_level then
    if current_chapter then
      local toc = current_chapter.toc
      toc[#toc+1] = head
    end
  end
  return nil
end

local function build_toc (heads)
  local toc = {}
  for _,head in ipairs(heads) do
    local entry = {
      pandoc.Plain{
        pandoc.Link(
          head.content:clone(), -- text
          '#' .. head.identifier, -- target
          "", -- empty title
          pandoc.Attr(
            "", -- empty identifier
            {'local-toc-link'} -- class
          )
        )
      }
    }
    toc[#toc+1] = entry
  end
  return pandoc.Div(
    { pandoc.BulletList(toc) },
    pandoc.Attr( "", {'local-toc'} )
  )
end


local function insert_toc (head)
  if head.level == chapter_level then
    local id = head.identifier
    if headings[id] then
      local toc = build_toc(
        headings[id].toc
      )
      return {head,toc}
    end
  end
  return nil
end

return {
  { Header = collect_headings },
  { Header = insert_toc },
}
```

Comment: How would I get this to add it after the section content and with a title of "Contents"